# TeraTermで複数タブ対応のソフトありますか？

Tags: teraterm

ブラウザと同じで、TeraTermは複数タブのソフトがありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeraTermも「ソフト名」なので、タブ対応のターミナルエミュレータを探してるという事でよいですかね。

- TeraTermも最近のリリースでは同梱の「Collector」を使えばタブ化できるようですが、あまり評判はよくなさそうです。
- 名前のせいで知名度は低いですが、「RLogin」辺りを試してみてはいかがでしょうか。
- 個人的には「Poderosa」のオープンソース版(4.x)を使用しています。

参考：
[多機能が魅力のターミナルエミュレーター「RLogin」 - 窓の杜](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/review/634233.html)
[Poderosa - OSDN](https://ja.osdn.net/projects/sfnet_poderosa/)